# Nested fors and if in list comprehension in python

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have this code:

```
for controller in se8650_list:
    for graphic in AS.client.get_children(controller + '/Application/$Graphics'):
        if 'Config' not in graphic._name:
            airflow_list.append(graphic._path)
```

`se8650_list` is just a list of strings (paths). It throws an exception:

> local variable 'controller' referenced before assignment

What did I do? Can I not have `controller` in the second for loop like that?

My real goal is a list comprehension version of this:

```
airflow_list = [graphic._path for graphic in AS.client.get_children(controller + '/Application/$Graphics') if 'Config' not in graphic._name for controller in se8650_list]
```

But I get errors there as well:

> name 'controller' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You list comprehension is constructed in the wrong way around. [The outer loop has to come first, followed by the inner loop](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3#nested-loops-in-a-list-comprehension).

But I would really recommend to not use a list comprehension at all. In my opinion, it makes the loops really hard to read and you should stick with the version without comprehension.

Try to keep the [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) in mind

```
[..]
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
[..]
```

or the following statement :D

[image]

Comment: Or use comprehensions but more than 1 and use intermediate variables.

Comment: yep! and try to use memory efficient [generator comprehensions](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db).